# ¿Como obtengo la url de un video de youtube en python?

Tags: python, discord.py

hace no mucho estoy trabajando en un bot para Discord y quiero añadirle la fucionalidad de que el bot (al igual que Rythm) busque tanto por URL proporcionada por el usuario o por palabras clave, es decir, introducir el nombre de la canción como por ejemplo "Thriller Michael Jackson" y que el bot busque a través de youtube el primer link que coincida con la busqueda. Por ahora solo he conseguido que reproduzca música introduciendo una URL en específico, pero introduciendo una palabra en clave no se me ocurre manera.

Estoy trabajando en python con las siguientes librerias:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
import asyncio
import youtube_dl
from ytsearch import youtube
```

Con las herramientas que me proporciona la librería de "ytsearch" lo único que puedo conseguir es que muestre el nombre de los vídeos en forma de lista, pero no veo la herramienta para que desde ahí me retorne una URL. Si alguien me pudiese aportar luz en el asunto le estaría muy agradecido.

Aqui dejo el fragmente de código donde el bot reproduciría el audio del video:

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def play(ctx,url):
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice_channel
    server = ctx.message.server
    await bot.join_voice_channel(channel)
    voice_client = bot.voice_client_in(server)
    player = await voice_client.create_ytdl_player(url)
    players[server.id] = player
    player.start()
    print("Me he metido en el canal {} para poner música".format(channel))
```

Así es como lo tengo estructurado ahora mismo, la idea sería si proporcionas a "URL" tanto una palabra en clave como un link, reprodujera el vídeo deseado. La solución se tendría que añadir encima de "player" para de esa forma no alterar el comportamiento del código

PD: perdón por la mala redacción

Comment: Con la libreria ytsearch ni idea, yo lo hago a pelo con beautifulsoup. Tienes un ejemplo en mi bot de ts3: https://github.com/Aens/Ts3PyBot/blob/master/Ts3PyBotGw2.py Busca la función `command_youtube`

Comment: @Saelyth Buah, no se como agradecertelo jajajaja. Es justo lo que estaba buscando, muchas gracias